# Is there a way to get File System root path in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making an education website which should display host file system.
Is there a way to get Operating System (or File System, I don't know exactly how it's called) root path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the server File System, yes:

```
Dir.glob('/*').each do |name|
  puts name
end
```